Optic API: How to split string with delimiter(comma) as a separate row
My optic query gives back a single row with one column named "activeIngredient," which holds a list of IDs separated by commas. Check out the JSON below.
[
    {
        "productId": 1234567899,
        "productName": "Test Product",
        "languageCode": "EN",
        "activeIngredient": "24622176,37690963,78121460",
        "updatedDate": "2021-08-12T10:42:21.6181006Z"
    }
]

I need to break down the ids from "activeIngredient" by using a comma to create separate rows.
I attempted to use op:map and loop through it, but it keeps giving me the last id, which is 78121460, for every row.
This is how I want my output to appear.
[
    {
        "productId": 1234567899,
        "productName": "Test Product",
        "languageCode": "EN",
        "activeIngredient": "24622176",
        "updatedDate": "2021-08-12T10:42:21.6181006Z"
    },
    {
        "productId": 1234567899,
        "productName": "Test Product",
        "languageCode": "EN",
        "activeIngredient": "37690963",
        "updatedDate": "2021-08-12T10:42:21.6181006Z"
    },
    {
        "productId": 1234567899,
        "productName": "Test Product",
        "languageCode": "EN",
        "activeIngredient": "78121460",
        "updatedDate": "2021-08-12T10:42:21.6181006Z"
    }
]

I am using MarkLogic v10.0-6.1.
I really appreciate any help you can offer.

If it's an option, I would split activeIngredient on ingest and make it an Array. It looks like they really should be separate values.

You can use op:bind() to modify the activeIngredient column and change it from a CSV to a tokenized set of values, and then use op:unnest-inner() to produce a row for each of those values:
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic"
     at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
import module namespace ofn="http://marklogic.com/optic/expression/fn"
     at "/MarkLogic/optic/optic-fn.xqy";

op:from-literals(
  map:new()
  => map:with("productId", 1234567899)
  => map:with("productName", "Test Product")
  => map:with("languageCode", "EN")
  => map:with("activeIngredient", "24622176,37690963,78121460")
  => map:with("updatedDate", "2021-08-12T10:42:21.6181006Z")
) 
=> op:bind((
     op:as("activeIngredient",  ofn:tokenize(op:col("activeIngredient"),  ","))
   ))
=> op:unnest-inner('activeIngredient','activeIngredient')   
=> op:result()

Which produces:



languageCode
productName
updatedDate
activeIngredient
productId




EN
Test Product
2021-08-12T10:42:21.6181006Z
24622176
1234567899


EN
Test Product
2021-08-12T10:42:21.6181006Z
37690963
1234567899


EN
Test Product
2021-08-12T10:42:21.6181006Z
78121460
1234567899




One more reason to upgrade!

Thank you for the answer, looks like op:unnest-inner() is not available in MarkLogic v10.0-6.1. Is there any other way to do the same in the mentioned MarkLogic version?

Edit: Updated with suggestion from Mads
For ML 10, if you know an upper limit to the number of ingredients per product, you can use a join-cross-product to expand out the rows.  Here is an example that supports up to 100 ingredients per product.  Note that making this too big can affect query scaling and memory usage, so you may have to play with it.
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic"
     at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
import module namespace ofn="http://marklogic.com/optic/expression/fn"
     at "/MarkLogic/optic/optic-fn.xqy";

let $products := op:from-literals(
  map:new()
  => map:with("productId", 1234567899)
  => map:with("productName", "Test Product")
  => map:with("languageCode", "EN")
  => map:with("activeIngredient", "24622176,37690963,78121460")
  => map:with("updatedDate", "2021-08-12T10:42:21.6181006Z")
)

let $pivot := op:from-literals((1 to 100)! map:entry("index", .))

return op:join-cross-product($products, $pivot)
=> op:bind((
     op:as("activeIngredient",  ofn:subsequence(ofn:tokenize(op:col("activeIngredient"),  ","), op:col("index"), 1))
   ))
=> op:where(ofn:exists(op:col("activeIngredient")))
=> op:result()




languageCode
index
productName
updatedDate
activeIngredient
productId




EN
3
Test Product
2021-08-12T10:42:21.6181006Z
78121460
1234567899


EN
2
Test Product
2021-08-12T10:42:21.6181006Z
37690963
1234567899


EN
1
Test Product
2021-08-12T10:42:21.6181006Z
24622176
1234567899




An easier way to ensure the pivot has enough items for the tokenized match is to generate a sequence: let $pivot := op:from-literals((1 to 1000)! map:entry("index", .))
